# O que este código do Arduino está fazendo?

Tags: c, arduino

Preciso de uma descrição do que ele faz.

```
if( ! digitalRead(sensor1)) {
    speed1 = frente;
    speedv1=0;
} else {
    speed1 = 0;
    speedv1 = voltar;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

O ideal seria ver o contexto, mas lendo ele dá para dizer:

- Chama uma função chamada `digitalRead()` passando como argumento o valor da variável `sensor1`. O que ela faz não temos como saber.
- Esta função deve retornar um valor booleano, ou pelo menos um 0 para falso ou outro valor que será tratado como verdadeiro. Se for falso, ou seja, se vier um 0, então o primeiro bloco entre chaves será executado, se vier qualquer outro valor o segundo bloco depois do comando `else` é que será executado. O `if` é um comando de decisão.
- No primeiro bloco a variável `speed1` para valer o valor que está na variável  `frente` neste momento e a variável `speedv1` passa valer 0.
- Se for para o segundo bloco `speed1` valerá 0 e `speedv1` valerá o mesmo que `voltar` neste momento.

Answer (score 0):

Se a leitura do sensor retornar qualquer informação ele seta as variaveis speed1 com "frente" e speedv1 com 0 se não retornar nada, a variável speedv1 fica com o valor "voltar" e speed1 também com 0 "Zero".